# "Cube1", "Cube2", "Cube3" instead of "Cube1.001", "Cube1.002" and "Cube1.003" when Duplicating

Tags: objects

When I copy objects, they automatically get numbered with ".001" or the next free decimal available. I often just select the objects in the View layer and rename into "Cube1, Cube2, Cube3" and so on. My question is if there is a way of telling blender to automatically number them in the way I prefer it. When my first cube is called "Cube1" and I copy and paste it, that blender just detects the number and calls the copy "Cube2" and 3 and 4 and so on for every copy instead of the "Cube.001" variant.

Comment: You can use batch rename (Ctrl+F2) with a regex to rename multiple objects.. A script that renames objects immediately when they are created will not work properly. Imagine a script that renames 'Cube.001' to 'Cube1' by simply removing the leading '0' (performance). This works. But if there is already 'Cube' and 'Cube1' then Blender still will make the name of a new 3rd cube unique. So the script will rename 'Cube.001' to 'Cube1' and Blender will rename it again to 'Cube1.001'. Then you have 'Cube', 'Cube1', and 'Cube1.001'. Next time the script checks it will rename it to 'Cube11'.

Comment: For batch rename, you can enter *Find:* `\.0+(\d+)$` - *Replace:* `\1` and click the star icons to enable regular expressions. This removes the period and the leading 0s in the numeric suffix.